# How to check if operation was cancelled?

Tags: swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I'd like to know whether my operation was cancelled or finished normally. Here is my code snippet :

```
class PacketReceiver {
    private let m_executer = OperationQueue()
    private var m_operation : Operation?

    private func operationFinishedHandler()
    {
        if let op = m_operation {
            if op.isCancelled {
                print("Operation cancelled")
            } else {
                print("Operation finished OK \(op.isCancelled)")
            }
        }
    }

    func start()
    {
        let rxPacketOperation = PacketReceiverOperation()
        rxPacketOperation.completionBlock = self.operationFinishedHandler
        m_operation = rxPacketOperation

        m_executer.addOperation(rxPacketOperation)
    }

    func cancel()
    {
        if let op = m_operation {
            op.cancel()
        }
    }

    func join()
    {
        if let op = m_operation {
            print("is op cancelled = \(op.isCancelled)")
        }

        m_executer.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()

        if let op = m_operation {
            print("is op cancelled = \(op.isCancelled)")
        }
    }
}
```

And later on I have :

```
let packetReceiver = PacketReceiver()
packetReceiver.start()

packetReceiver.cancel()
packetReceiver.join()
```

I see that inside `join()` method `isCancelled` property is set to true. But when I check it inside finished handler it is false. I guess it's an expected behaviour. But what is the correct way to check whether my operation was cancelled or not?

This is my operation class :

```
class PacketReceiverOperation : Operation {
    private var m_packetData : String = ""
    private let m_simDataProvider = SimDataProvider(okAttemptId : 2)
    private let m_currentTimeProvider = CurrentTimeProvider()

    private func prepareReceiver() {
        m_packetData = ""
        print("\(m_currentTimeProvider.getCurrentTimeAsString()) : prepare SIM receiver")
    }

    override func main() {
        if isCancelled {
            return
        }

        prepareReceiver()

        if isCancelled {
            return
        }

        var isPacketReceived = false
        var isFirstChunkReceived = false

        repeat {
            if isCancelled {
                return
            }

            if let chunkData = m_simDataProvider.getPacket() {
                isFirstChunkReceived = true
                m_packetData.append(";" + chunkData)
            } else {
                if isFirstChunkReceived {
                    isPacketReceived = true
                }
            }
        } while isPacketReceived == false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a variety of reasons (notably the lack of preemptive cancelation and general race conditions) the `isCancelled` state is not a reliable way of knowing whether your `Operation` subclass finished successfully or not, regardless. (It tells you whether you attempted cancelation, but not whether the underlying task succeeded or not.)

For this reason, I rarely use the built in `completionHandler` (with no parameters) and instead generally implement my own custom completion handler closure that supplies a `Result` (or whatever) as parameter. This eliminates all ambiguity.

Or, in your case, you could make `isPacketReceived` a property of your operation, instead of a local variable, and then you could look at that to determine whether a packet was completely received or not rather than `isCancelled`.

You later said:

> I see that `completionHandler` is invoked after `join()` finishes.

Yes, that’s true.

But it’s a bit worrisome that `join` is a synchronous method, at all, (i.e. that you’re calling `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`). The intent of operation queues is so we can adopt asynchronous patterns for potentially time consuming tasks and get this stuff off the main thread. Blocking while we wait for an operation to finish (especially if you’re calling `join` from the main thread) would seem to defeat that purpose.

I’d encourage you to embrace the asynchronous pattern and just add your operation to a queue and initiate whatever you need in its completion handler (whether the default one or your own).

Comment: Just put my operation implementation 4 u. Also I see that completionHandler is invoked after join() finishes. And moreover I'm able to call start() again before completionHandler is called... As I found here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408085-completionblock it seems that there is no guarantee about exact time for handler to be called. Am I right?

Comment: For the moment my current solution to check operation exit status is the following :
    func join()
    {
        m_executer.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
        if let op = m_operation {
            if op.isCancelled {
                print("Operatuion finished : CANCELLED")
            } else {
                print("Operatuion finished : NORMALLY")
            }
        }
    }

Comment: “it seems that there is no guarantee about exact time for handler to be called. Am I right?” ... yes, that is true. This is another reason why I often implement my own completion handler. I can dictate when precisely it’s called and what parameter(s) are supplied.